# Windows Command to delete existing directory and create new

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I have a "release" folder inside c:\data.

I would like to delete the entire "release" folder, its sub directories and all files inside them using windows commands. After deleting it, I need to recreate the "release" folder and add another folder "app" inside "release" folder using commands.

I tried using rd /s and few other commands but it complains about non empty directory and workarounds to re-try rd /s command. I thought it should be fairly easy to do. Does anyone have a script / commands for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RM` is not a windows cmd command. This should work:

```
IF EXIST "c:\data\" (
    RD c:\data\release /S /Q
    MD c:\data\release
    MD c:\data\release\app
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can of course remove ([`rd`](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html)) and recreate ([`md`](https://ss64.com/nt/md.html)) a directory. However, you will lose its attributes then (like Hidden or Owner).

To maintain attributes, remove the contents of the directory but not the directory itself, either doing something like this:

```cmd
rem // First remove all sub-directories with all their contents:
for /D %%I in ("C:\Data\release\*") do rd /S /Q "%%~I"
rem // Then delete any files located in the target directory:
del /Q /A "*.*"
```

Or this:

```cmd
rem // Change into the target directory:
cd /D "C:\Data\release"
rem /* Try to remove the target directory and all its contents; since you are
rem    in the target directory, it cannot be removed, although its contents can;
rem    the `2> nul` portion suppresses the error message about access problems: */
rd /S /Q "." 2> nul
```